# Using SharpFFmpeg.dll for video conversion

Tags: c#

In my c# application , i am using SharpFFMpeg.dll library for storing video and image files.

And the video files we upload from flex application, which supports flv and some few format of videos only.So when some one upload any type of video format, we planned to convert it into flv.

Before we store the data in database we convert the uploaded file to .tmp file (setting hashcode of uploaded file and adding extension as .tmp) and store temporarily this file in internetcache, as below.

```
string filename = element.Filename;
                    string internetCache = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
                    // if the internet path doesn't exist, assume mono and /var/tmp
                    string path = string.IsNullOrEmpty(internetCache)
                               ? Path.Combine("var", "tmp")
                               : Path.Combine(internetCache.Replace("\\\\", "\\"), "tmp");
                    element.Filename = Path.Combine(path, Math.Abs(element.Filename.GetHashCode()) + ".tmp");
```

And while checking the type of file is written as below.

```
IntPtr pFormatContext;
            FFmpeg.av_register_all();

            int ret;
            ret = FFmpeg.av_open_input_file(out pFormatContext, this.Filename, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            if (ret < 0)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("couldn't open input file");

                FFmpeg.av_free_static();
                return;
            }


            try
            {
                ret = FFmpeg.av_find_stream_info(pFormatContext);
                if (ret < 0)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine("couldnt find stream informaion");
                    FFmpeg.av_close_input_file(pFormatContext);
                    FFmpeg.av_free_static();
                    return;
                }


                FFmpeg.AVFormatContext formatContext = (FFmpeg.AVFormatContext)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pFormatContext, typeof(FFmpeg.AVFormatContext));

                Duration = formatContext.duration / FFmpeg.AV_TIME_BASE;

                for (int i = 0; i < formatContext.nb_streams; ++i)
                {
                    FFmpeg.AVStream stream = (FFmpeg.AVStream)Marshal.PtrToStructure(formatContext.streams[i], typeof(FFmpeg.AVStream));
                    FFmpeg.AVCodecContext codec = (FFmpeg.AVCodecContext)Marshal.PtrToStructure(stream.codec, typeof(FFmpeg.AVCodecContext));

                    if (codec.codec_type == FFmpeg.CodecType.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO)
                    {
                        Height = codec.height;
                        Width = codec.width;

                        switch (codec.codec_id)
                        {
                            case FFmpeg.CodecID.CODEC_ID_FLV1:
                            case FFmpeg.CodecID.CODEC_ID_VP6F:
                            case FFmpeg.CodecID.CODEC_ID_H264:
                            case FFmpeg.CodecID.CODEC_ID_MPEG4:
                                Type = FileType.flv;
                                MimeType = "video/x-flv";
                                break;
```

But if i upload like avi the above code is not working.
Please help me in the video conversion, by using the SharpFFMPeg dll.

Comment: One have to be said... No one is going to help us...